# how do I find/select image height from an img I created within a jQuery function inside that function?

Tags: jquery, image, function, height

```
$("img").click(function () {
    $("#galleryImg").html("<img src='images/full_size/" + selectedImg + "' alt='" + selectedImg + "' />");
    var imgHeight = $("#galleryImg img").height();
}
```

The method I'm using right now is not working and I can't use $(this) because the image that I want the height from is different from the image I am clicking on. And to complicate it a little bit more, the image I want the height from is having its html img tag being created within the function.

The whole piece of code of the relevant area is as below

```
$("img").click(function () {
    $("div#blackOut").fadeTo(550, 0.8);
    $("div#whiteBox").fadeTo(550, 1);

    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var browserWidth = $(window).width();

    var imgName = $(this).attr("src");

    var imgArray = $(this).attr('src').split('\/');
    var selectedImg = imgArray[imgArray.length-1];

    $("#galleryImg").html("<img src='images/full_size/" + selectedImg + "' alt='" + selectedImg + "' />");

    $("#galleryImg img").load(function() {
        var thatHeight = $("#galleryImg img").height();

        alert(thatHeight);
    });

    var top = (browserHeight - (imgHeight + 50)) / 2;
    var width = imgHeight + 50;
    var marginLeft = -(width / 2);

    var top = top + "px";
    var width = width + "px";
    var marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";

    $("#whiteBox").css("top", top);
    $("#whiteBox").css("width", "width");
    $("#whiteBox").css("margin-left", "marginLeft");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the image to load before getting its height:

```
$("#galleryImg").html("<img src='images/full_size/" + selectedImg + "' alt='" + selectedImg + "' />");
$("#galleryImg img").load(function() {
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: I've tried using your code and a few variations of it but I'm keeping getting a height of '0'. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Perhaps some CSS is influencing the sizing of the image instead of it being auto-sized according to content.

Comment: thanks for looking into my question. I added the rest of the code in the function I was using and exactly as how I was testing it after reading your suggestion. I'm still getting a height of 0 in my code after using your suggestion. One thing that does seem odd is that the alert showing the height is appearing before the html actually loads, so I'm thinking there might be some sort of loading order problem. I still need the height value in the same function however because I'm using it to calculate values for some other css properties related to the img html code being created.

Comment: nevermind, your function works as intended in internet explorer. My chrome browser is giving me trouble.